# Calling a Remote EJB running on a Weblogic instance using Host & Port name

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I have a question about calling a Remote EJB (3.0) running on a Weblogic instance using Host & Port name of the Weblogic Server.

I've read the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf) specifically about invoking a remote EJB either through JNDI or through Dependency Injection.

But the environment (Common Dev environment) I work with has client code that accesses the EJB through a host name and a port name using Spring.

I have a local instance of Weblogic and deployed the ear file. I wanted to follow the same workflow (using the host name and the portname) to call this ejb on my local machine (the client will be running on another application server locally) to see if remote attachment to my ejb works. But I'm not sure what the deal is with the port number. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, as far as the calling client is concerned, it's accessing the Remote EJB's via RMI via JNDI.  It shouldn't be all that different.

Spring does have some native support for accessing the remote EJBs

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#ejb-access

Typically, when you have the host/port of the remote server, that's part of the InitialContext  object created for the JNDI Context.  It also looks like there is some Spring components that look after this mapping: in the context.xml, there is jee:local-slsb.  I don't know if there is an equivalent for annotations.

I haven't done any of this myself, but the documentation is probably a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Spring reference document. The calls to the EJB are similar that of the documentation as expected. I'm wondering how to find out the port that I need to use for the EJB running on my local weblogic instance. Is the port number same as the default 7001? Or where can I find the associated configuration (config.xml, setDomainEnv.cmd etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, typically the default JNDI port for WebLogic instances is 7001.  There's nothing preventing a WebLogic instance from assigning it to a different port, though.  You can try 7001 and if it can't find the remote host, you'll need to check with the people looking after the server to tell you which port it's using.

Comment: It's been a few years since I've worked with WebLogic in anger.  I can't recall where in the WebLogic config this would be stored.  Sorry.